# Wing IDE + Python 2.4: no module named functools

Tags: python, functools, wing-ide

I need to use Python 2.4 to be compatible with an old Python extension not easily replaced. So I installed Python 2.4 and wing IDE 101 v.6, and directed Wing to use that Python (it wasn't automatic). I have done this combination many times before on Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines, but this time I did it on Windows 10, and I'm seeing a brand-new error: the moment the shell starts it reports "No module named functools". Full stack dump below. Any suggestions on how to configure things to make this work?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 875, in main
    winghome, user_settings = _GetWingDirs(orig_sys_argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 79, in _GetWingDirs
    winghome = _GetUnicodeEnvValue('WINGDB_WINGHOME')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 54, in _GetUnicodeEnvValue
    _minimal_win32_module = _LoadModuleFromWingbaseDir('minimalwin32')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 634, in _LoadModuleFromWingbaseDir
    mergeimporter = _LoadModuleFromDir(mod_name, os.path.dirname(mod_full_path))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 530, in _LoadModuleFromDir
    return imp.load_module(mod_name, fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin/dbg/src/wingbase\minimalwin32.py", line 36, in ?
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools
```

Comment: Not familiar with Wing, but is there not a difference between the version that the IDE uses for itself and the version it uses for your programming environment?  Are you sure you didn't set the former instead of the latter?  `functools` came with Python2.5, so if your IDE is trying to use Python 2.4 as _its_ Python, the error makes sense.

Comment: Yes, Wing uses a stripped down private copy of Python 2.7 internally but that's isn't the issue here.  Instead, it's some of the debugger code assuming it can import functools because Wing 6 doesn't support Python <= 2.4 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Functools did not exist until version 2.5:

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)

> New in version 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Wing 6 does not support Python 2.4.  You'll need to use Wing 5 for that.